# Selenium: How do I get the locator of the element which currently holds the cursor?

Tags: testing, selenium, firebug

I'm writing an auto testing framework using Selenium.  I am trying to test our application which interacts with a third party web application.  I don't have access to the source code of the web app.

I want to be able to use selenium to put some text in a text box, but no matter how hard I try, selenium IDE isn't able to record me putting text into this box.

Firebug seems to imply that this is because the box that I am trying to write to is with a separate html form imbedded with the page.  However, I am able to interact with the web app so that the cursor is in the text box.

Is there a way to either:

a) Input text at the current cursor position (i.e. without referencing a locator because I can't seem to be able to get the locator.)

or,

b) Get the locator of the element which currently holds the cursor?

Thanks in advance,
Rik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an iframe you need to change the focus to iframe and try to do the actions.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks!